# Updating layout anchors not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have created a view with height 100 using NSLayout anchors. When I'm trying to update that on button click, it's not working.

I have tried below code, but it's not working.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    let viewAnimate = UIView()
    var isHidden = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(viewAnimate)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        viewAnimate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewAnimate.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        viewAnimate.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        viewAnimate.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        viewAnimate.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        viewAnimate.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    @IBAction func show() {

        if !isHidden {
            viewAnimate.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
            button.setTitle("Show", for: .normal)
        } else {
            button.setTitle("Hide", for: .normal)
            viewAnimate.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.viewAnimate.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        isHidden = !isHidden
    }
}
```

View should change the height based on height constraint

Comment: you are creating a new constraint every time with .constraint(...) so eventually you will have a conflict (as the view has both height constraints to 100 AND 200). Create the constraint as in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

Your current code creates conflicts as every line like `viewAnimate.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:` adds a new constraint , create a var

```
var topCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

---

```
topCon = viewAnimate.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
topCon.isActive = true
```

---

```
@IBAction func show() {

        if !isHidden { 
            topCon.constant = 200
            button.setTitle("Show", for: .normal)
        } else {
            button.setTitle("Hide", for: .normal)
            topCon.constant = 100
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        isHidden = !isHidden
}
```